# Dynamically Add Javascript and CSS Files in CodeIgniter Head section

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I have same header for different page with different design. I have to add all css files in header section which increases page loading.
My question is, is there a way to load css file dynamically to header section.I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: what do you mean load css file dynamically?

Comment: if you are adding your header view dynamically then you can add variable to header and send it form controller like `load->view('header.php',$css_js_var)`

Comment: I think this one is the best ide

Answer (score 0):

To implement this in CodeIgniter, firstly set the default CSS and JavaScript files in config.php

```
$config['header_css'] = array('style.css','prettyPhoto.css','nivo-slider.css');
$config['header_js']  = array('core.js','core.js',
                          'jquery-1.4.1.min.js',
                          'jquery-slidedeck.pack.lite.js',
                          'jquery-prettyPhoto.js',
                          'jquery.nivo.slider.js');
```

then, add this helper functions I wrote, to your template helper (or any other helper files you use)

```
//Dynamically add Javascript files to header page
if(!function_exists('add_js')){
function add_js($file='')
{
    $str = '';
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $header_js  = $ci->config->item('header_js');

    if(empty($file)){
        return;
    }

    if(is_array($file)){
        if(!is_array($file) && count($file) <= 0){
            return;
        }
        foreach($file AS $item){
            $header_js[] = $item;
        }
        $ci->config->set_item('header_js',$header_js);
    }else{
        $str = $file;
        $header_js[] = $str;
        $ci->config->set_item('header_js',$header_js);
    }
}
}

//Dynamically add CSS files to header page
if(!function_exists('add_css')){
function add_css($file='')
{
    $str = '';
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $header_css = $ci->config->item('header_css');

    if(empty($file)){
        return;
    }

    if(is_array($file)){
        if(!is_array($file) && count($file) <= 0){
            return;
        }
        foreach($file AS $item){   
            $header_css[] = $item;
        }
        $ci->config->set_item('header_css',$header_css);
    }else{
        $str = $file;
        $header_css[] = $str;
        $ci->config->set_item('header_css',$header_css);
    }
}
}

if(!function_exists('put_headers')){
function put_headers()
{
    $str = '';
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $header_css = $ci->config->item('header_css');
    $header_js  = $ci->config->item('header_js');

    foreach($header_css AS $item){
        $str .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url().'css/'.$item.'" type="text/css" />'."\n";
    }

    foreach($header_js AS $item){
        $str .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_url().'js/'.$item.'"></script>'."\n";
    }

    return $str;
}
}
```

Now, you can manually add CSS and JavaScript files as below:

```
add_css(array('demo.css','demo1.css'));
add_js('demo.js');
```

Comment: You can follow this [link](http://jamshidhashimi.com/2013/04/12/dynamically-add-javascript-and-css-files-in-codeigniter-header-page/), I had copied form there

Comment: Thanks Umar khan,
I have already used it.But it does not work properly.